# Jquery Modal Popup opens twice on Single Click with ASP.Net MVC3

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-3, events, jquery-events

I am using Modal Popup in my MVC3 application it works fine but opens twice for a single Click on the link.

The Modal pop is triggered from the 'Index' view of my Home Controller. I am calling a view `PopUp.cshtml` in my modal popup. The related `ActionMethod` 'PopUp' for the respective view is in my 'Home' controller.

Here is the code:

**Jquery code on layout.cshtml page,**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $.ajaxSetup({ cache: false });

    $(document).ready(function () {
        $(".openPopup").live("click", function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();

            $("<div></div><p>")
                    .attr("id", $(this).attr("data-dialog-id"))
                    .appendTo("body")
                    .dialog({
                        autoOpen: true,
                        title: $(this).attr("data-dialog-title"),
                        modal: true,
                        height: 250,
                        width: 900,
                        left: 0,
                        buttons: { "Close": function () { $(this).dialog("close"); } }
                    })
                    .load(this.href);
        });

        $(".close").live("click", function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            $(this).dialog("close");
        });
    });
    </script>
```

**cshtml code in 'PopUp.cshtml'**

```
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "PopUp";
    Layout = null;
}

<h2>PopUp</h2>

<p>
Hello this is a Modal Pop-Up
</p>
```

**Call modal popup code in Index view of Home Controller,**

```
<p>
   @Html.ActionLink("Click here to open modal popup", "Popup", "Home",null, new { @class = "openPopup", data_dialog_id = "popuplDialog", data_dialog_title = "PopUp" })
</p>
```

What am I doing wrong that the modal pop up opens twice ?

Comment: It is not clear how many elements that match `.openPopup` you have in the same ancestor chain. Events bubble up. Try calling `stopPropagation()` in addition to `preventDefault()` (or just return `false` from the handler).

Comment: @Frédéric: Its not working I am still closing the PopUp twice...

Comment: is the javascript being loaded twice? I've had some issues where the live command was called twice and the event was executing twice.

Comment: Thanks @ChadKapatch !
But I am not sure how it is called twice... I even commented the last section in the JQuery code in Layout.cshtml page. 

$(".close").live("click", function (e) {             e.preventDefault();             
$(this).dialog("close");         
});

But still no luck...

Comment: Can you replicate the issue in a jsFiddle?

Answer (score 0):

Try this. It checks whether there is already a dialog present and not, it creates one.

Also make sure you do not have your click event binded in more than one places( check for inner / outer elements also)

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function(){
        $(document).on("click",".openPopup",function (e) {
            var url = this.href;
            var dialog = $("#dialog");
            if ($("#dialog").length == 0) {
                dialog = $('<div id="dialog" style="display:hidden"></div>').appendTo('body');
            }
            dialog.load(
                url,
                {}, // omit this param object to issue a GET request instead a POST request, otherwise you may provide post parameters within the object
                function (responseText, textStatus, XMLHttpRequest) {
                    dialog.dialog({                       
                        close: function (event, ui) {                            
                            dialog.remove();
                        },
                        modal: true,
                        width: 460, resizable: false
                    });
                }
            );           
            return false;           
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: This is more of a workaround. The orginal script should work fine, there something that I am missing or doing wrong... which is opening the pop-up twice....

Comment: if not for this is there any other way that I can implement this (call a view from controller in a modal pop up on click of a link on Home Controller)...